# Edit summary text field can be submitted without any description by using spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, edit-summary, validation

The edit summary text field when submitting an edit does not validate space. A user can press the space bar a few times and submit the summary without any description.

Comment: I am not sure if this is intended but think is a Bug. As there is a word restriction in it. So I guess users are expected to put something before saving

Comment: I think it’s more a safeguard against accidental submission; an edit message isn’t required once you have editing privileges, and space-only suggested edit summaries aren’t likely to be accepted. (Not to say that this isn’t a valid bug.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added space checking to the edit summary.

With you in the next build.